# how to implement Softmax function for neural networks in processing 3 environment?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

I tried programming a neural network in [processing IDE](https://processing.org/).
I managed to do it quite well, until I tried using the MNIST handwritten digits data set. I tried the [iris data set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/iris) and few others from [UCI machine learning repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html), but when I used the MNIST data set it didn't worked. for some reason all of the outputs approached zero with time, and that caused the total error to be always equal to 1. I am almost sure that my problem is the activation function; so I tried using softmax for classification, but it wasn't very successful. I got the same results. I think maybe I should have use a different loss function, so I tried the negative log probability according to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlaLLQofmR8) video. the results now are the same cost value for each output neuron, and the sum of the outputs is not 1 as it should be.
Here are the functions for each part of the code that I have changed (I prefer not to share the full code because it's long and messy, and not really helpful):

softmax:

```
float[] softmax(float[] inputVector){
  float[] result = new float[inputVector.length];
  float sigma = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < inputVector.length; i++){
    sigma += exp(inputVector[i]);
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
    result[i] = exp(inputVector[i]) / sigma;
  }
  return result;
}
```

derivative of softmax:

```
float[] derivativeSoftmax(float[] inputVector){
  float[] result = new float[inputVector.length];
  for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
    result[i] = softmax(inputVector)[i] * (1 - softmax(inputVector)[i]);
  }
  return result;
}
```

loss function:

```
for(int i = 0; i < outputNeuronsNumber; i++){
  float tempSigma = 0;
  for(int j = 0; j < outputNeuronsNumber; j++){
    tempSigma += target[diffCounter2] * log(outputLayer[j]);
  }
  cost[i] = -tempSigma;
}
```

I can't see what is the problem with my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
float[] derivativeSoftmax(float[] inputVector){
  float[] result = new float[inputVector.length];
  for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
    result[i] = softmax(inputVector)[i] * (1 - softmax(inputVector)[i]);
  }
  return result;
}
```

I believe this is wrong, given the derivative of the softmax [as defined on wikipedia](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/5aa232271cfda7808dc98502a019c28e6fe6b48d).

```
float[] derivativeSoftmax(float[] inputVector, int k){
  float[] result = new float[inputVector.length];
  for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
    result[i] = softmax(inputVector)[i] * ((i==k ? 1 : 0) - softmax(inputVector)[k]);
  }
  return result;
}
```

You should be taking the derivative at an index with respect to some other index. The equation as you have it, which is x*(1-x) doesn't make a lot of sense. But I may be wrong.

Comment: according to the link you sent, maybe it will be easier to rewrite the normal softmax function, and by that the derivative will be correct? and why does all the cost values are the same?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by rewriting the original softmax function, it is correct. Sometimes cost values are all the same because somewhere you are doing scalar addition/multiplication where you should be doing vector addition/multiplication. This is just one of many possibilities, but "having all your outputs be the same" is a pretty good indicator of this bug.